# Derivation of the probability distribution function of a log-normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, logarithms, normal-distribution

[image]

Let [image] and [image] be respectively the cumulative probability distribution function and the probability density function of the N(0,1) distribution.

In the above image, I understand why **d/dx(Pr(lnX <= lnx))** has been done.
But why have we normalized it to **(lnx - μ)/(σ)** while inputting it into the cumulative distribution function(Φ)?

I believe we just input the raw values into the CDF rather than the normalized ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$. If $Y=\frac  {\ln X-\mu} {\sigma}$ then $Y \sim N(0,1)$ and $\Phi$ is the distribution function of $Y$. So $P(\ln X \leq t)=P( \mu +\sigma Y \leq t)=P(Y \leq \frac {t-\mu} {\sigma})=\Phi (\frac {t-\mu} {\sigma})$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln X$ is assumed to follow $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, so you could input $\ln x$ into the distribution function of $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. But if you want to relate this to the distribution function of $N(0, 1)$, you have to normalize $\ln x$ before inputting it into $\Phi$.